# How to load custom file from storyboard scene?

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard

[image]General our used `loadNibNamed:` to load XIB file, but when i watching WWDC 2015 session what's new in storyboard, I find we can use a special method to load view or cell to storyboard scene, it's very interesting for me, i don't know how to load  this external view. I used `loadNibNamed:` method, but it not work. I want to know than how to load external view ? I worked Xcode 9.4.1 and macOS 10.14. If any one have opinions please tell me, thanks!

Comment: You can create its outlet in controller and further you can set its frame or use outlets.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! @AbuUlHassan I will have a try.